# docker ps --format "{{.Names}} {{.State}}" not working

Tags: docker

Command executed:

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}} {{.State}}"
```

Error thrown:

```
Template parsing error: template: :1:13: executing "" at <.State>: can't evaluate field State in type *formatter.containerContext
```

Docker version using : Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

I expect container names and state(for example; “created”, “running”, “exited”).

I referred this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#format), but that doesn't help.

Comment: Your documentation link points to the StackOverflow homepage.

Comment: What version of docker are you running. works fine for me ...

Comment: Updated the doc link @AymDev

Comment: Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d @derpirscher

Comment: Well, the `.State` wasn't introduced until version 20.10 https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/20.10/  Your version is nearly 4 years old ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.State` placeholder [was added in July 2019](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2000) and is available since **Docker 20.10** (see [20.10.0 Client release notes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/20.10/#client-7)).

Having an old version installed I get the same output:

```bash
docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

```bash
docker ps --format "{{.Names}} {{.State}}"
Template parsing error: template: :1:13: executing "" at <.State>: can't evaluate field State in type *formatter.containerContext
```

Formatting as JSON shows that there is no `State` key:

```bash
docker ps --format "{{json .}}"
{"Command":"...","CreatedAt":"...","ID":"...","Image":"...","Labels":"...","LocalVolumes":"...","Mounts":"...","Names":"...","Networks":"...","Ports":"...","RunningFor":"...","Size":"...","Status":"..."}
```